# QuartzCore Leak

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am using following code to give round corners to the image placed on a uiimageview

```
imgUserImage=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imgUserImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kAddImageUserBlank]];
imgUserImage.frame=CGRectMake(20.0, 70.0, 110.0, 110.0);
CALayer * l = [imgUserImage layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:15.0];
[[self view] addSubview:imgUserImage];
```

I am getting a leak in the instrument which says mem_alloc and responsible library is QuartzCore.

Or is there any other way to give rounded corners to the image.

Please advise.

Comment: you are using arc right? is your imguserimage set as strong?

Comment: no...rather i dint create any property for it...

Comment: Please show the declaration of `imgUserImage`, and specify whether ARC is on or off. (If it's off, add `autorelease` to the `alloc` line.)

Comment: i declared the imgUserImage in .h,my deployment target starts from 3.0 so I am not using ARC and i am releasing this imgUserImage in dealloc of the current view controller because I am using setting the image of the user taken from the camera somewhere else in the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Why don't you use the following?

```
imgUserImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kAddImageUserBlank]];
```

2)Try to use instead of your last string:

```
[[self view] addSubview:[imgUserImage autorelease]];
```

or

```
[[self view] addSubview:imgUserImage];
//And then wnen you don't need it anymore
[imgUserImage release];
```

Comment: trying it...a change here UIImageView here instead of UIImage...in the first line...:)

Comment: i tried more than couple of times...instrument now does not reporoduce that leak...thanks!!